# A question on the universal property of the direct sum of abelian groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, category-theory, abelian-groups, universal-property

As I learnt in another question that I posted here, the result stated [here](https://ysharifi.wordpress.com/2019/09/26/group-homomorphism-direct-product-1/)  is the universal property of the direct sum of abelian groups written for finitely many abelian groups. Here is what I still don't get. I know that the direct sum of abelian groups is not the same as the direct sum of not necessarily abelian groups. I also know that the direct sum of finitely many abelian groups is the same as their direct product. Is this the reason why the $G_1, G_2, ..., G_n$ groups mentioned there are not taken to be abelian? Do we need them to be abelian only if we aren't working with finitely many groups?

Comment: You need them to be abelian for the map $\varphi$ to be a group homomorphism. Note that the homomorphism set $\mathrm{Hom}(H,K)$ is not a group when $K$ is not abelian, so the claim that $\varphi$ is a group homomorphism cannot even get started unless the target group is abelian.  But you can still define the *function* for any group. If $G$ (the target) is abelian, then the universal property of the *abelianization* tells you that it doesn’t matter whether the $G_i$ are abelian, because maps into abelian groups factor through $G_i^{\rm ab}$ and $G_1^{\rm ab}\times\cdots\times G_n^{\rm ab}$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I see, so basically in my link they prove the universal property of the direct sum step by step, making a certain assumption only when it is necessary.

Comment: Note that this is not the “universal property”. This is just the assertion that the map from $\prod \mathrm{Hom}(G_i,G)$ to $\mathrm{Hom}(G_1\times\cdots\times G_n,G)$ is a group homomorphism. The universal property requires uniqueness, and in fact that this is a group **isomorphism**. That is not generally satisfied if the $G_i$ are not assumed to be abelian.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin yes, now I get it, that's why I deleted my initial comment, I initially misunderstood what you wrote. Without the $G_i$ being abelian we can just define that injective map, which is part a) from there. Part b) is the universal property and, as I said, the author of the blogpost just decided to prove it step by step, making a certain assumption only when necessary.

Comment: You can leverage it to get an isomorphism in general, by going through the abelianizations, provided $G$ is abelian; but the universal property is generally applied where all groups are of the same kind (they should all be in the same category). This is a “not-quite-universal property” because it is not “for every group”, just “for every group that happens to be abelian”.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I see. One final question. One of my peers told me that the result I linked can be regarded as a particular case of the universal property of the coproduct. Is he right? After your explanations I am not really sure on whether he is right to call it like that.

Comment: The direct sum of abelian groups is the coproduct in the category of all abelian groups. In that sense, stating the universal property of the direct sum for abelian groups is a special case of the coproduct. But if you don’t assume that all the groups you are working with are abelian, then you don’t have a special case of a coproduct. The coproduct for arbitrary groups is the free product.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin thank you, now I understand.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I know I said it was the last question, but another thing came to my mind. Even though that result I linked is not a particular case of the universal property of the coproduct, can we still say that the statement has its roots in category theory? This is from where the discussion between me and that friend started, from whether the statement has its roots in category theory or not.

Comment: I honestly do not know if the result in groups precedes category theory or not. I would guess that it does precede it, so that this property was known before category theory was even laid down. The precise way of phrasing it may be inspired by Category Theory, but then again it may be the other way around. Category Theory is fairly “young” compared to group theory. Abstract group theory dates from the mid 19th century (via Arthur Cayley), while category theory was introduced by Mac Lane and Eilenberg in the early 1940s, almost 100 years later.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin thank you for all your time!