# The universal property of the direct product of groups is a particular case of the universal property of the product in a category?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, logic, category-theory, universal-property

I have posted here quite a bit on different ways of stating the universal property of the direct product and of the direct sum of (abelian) groups. Once again, I have a question which most likely comes from the fact that I am only a beginner when it comes to category theory.
Is it correct to say that the universal property of the direct product of groups is a particular case of the universal property of the product in a category? In this post [A question on the universal property of the direct sum of abelian groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4060492/835419) I learnt that stating the universal property of the direct sum of abelian groups is a particular case of the universal property of the coproduct. That's why I assume that the same conclusion is valid if we change the coproduct to the product. But I would like to understand why this is correct. Isn't the universal property of the product in a category just a definition? I think that the universal property of the direct product of groups needs to be proved, so it may be regarded as a theorem. How can a theorem be a particular case of a definition? I am sorry if this is all obvious/trivial, but I really want to understand this.
EDIT: I thought about this now, let me know if I am correct. We may also define the direct product of groups through its universal property. In this way, this is no longer a theorem. And I guess that from here we may deduce that the direct product of groups can be presented the way we are used with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The universal property of the direct product of groups is precisely the universal property in the category of groups $\mathbf{Grp}$.

But as you should remember, an universal property does tell us the existence of an object! On the other hand, once we have found an object that satisfies the universal property, then it is the unique object up to unique isomorphism that satisfies the universal property - which is why we may speak of *the* product if it exists.

So in our particular case, we explicitly construct the direct product of groups $G \times H$ and then prove that it satisfies the universal property of products in $\mathbf{Grp}$. Only then can we feel confident to call $G \times H$ product and sleep at ease at night.

Comment: Thank you! So, there is nothing wrong with the statement I made, right?  The universal property of the direct product of groups truly is a particular case of the universal property of the product in a category, even though we may need to prove that it holds. Is the thing I added in the edit correct, that we may just take the definition of the direct product of groups to be that given by the universal property of the cateogrical product and prove afterwards that this direct product is the one that we are used with (and I think that this also grants us the existence of the object)?

Comment: Yes, that is OK. :-) But maybe you should rather say that you prove that the explicit definition satisfies the universal property. As mentioned, if you just give the universal property, you have not given an object yet, as it need to exist.

Comment: @TheZone "...even though we may need to prove that it holds" doesn't sound so good. This is not a feature of $\mathbf{Grp}$, one always has to do it. Again, a universal property is just some property that objects may satisfy and one then constructs objects which do satisfy the property.

Comment: I see, this is where my confusion came from: I didn't understand why we say that the universal property of the direct product of groups is a particular case, when we actually need to prove that the direct product, in the way we are used with it,  satisfies that property. This was in contrast to the categorical product, which is just a definition (I know the motivation behind the definition, but strictly speaking, it is still just a definition).

Comment: But now I understand that there is nothing wrong if we say that the universal property of the direct product of groups is a particular case of the universal property of the categorical product and then we actually go on to show that our direct product satisfies that universal property, right? (Sorry for splitting it into two comments, my comment got too long)

Comment: @TheZone Yes, that's basically right. But I wouldn't say it is in contrast to the categorical product. The word "category" is nothing mysterious, here the category is just $\mathbf{Grp}$. It is also at first just a definition (of a property). Then, the cool thing is that there actually exists something which has this property in $\mathbf{Grp}$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time! I am just starting out with these things and I don't really have anyone to ask, I always appreciate the users from here that spend a lot of time answering my (sometimes pretty dumb) questions.

Comment: @TheZone These things are definitely not easy, I remember also struggling a bit when I was starting out with universal properties. Keep at it :)